# @JsonPropertyOrder names independent of property naming strategy

Tags: java, serialization, jackson, jackson-databind, jackson2

We have a model like:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
        "id",
        "alpha2_code",
        "alpha3_code",
        "name"
})
@Getter
@Setter
public class Country {

    private Long id;
    private String alpha2Code;
    private String alpha3Code;
    private String name;
}
```

and a `ObjectMapper` instance like:

```
var jsonMapper = new ObjectMapper();
jsonMapper.enable(SerializationFeature.INDENT_OUTPUT);
jsonMapper.disable(SerializationFeature.WRITE_DATES_AS_TIMESTAMPS);
jsonMapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategies.SNAKE_CASE);
jsonMapper.registerModule(new JavaTimeModule());
```

to create the following JSON:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "alpha2_code": "NL",
  "alpha3_code": "NLD",
  "name": "Netherlands",
}
```

This works all as expected.

What important to mention is that we are using `@JsonPropertyOrder` to sort the output.
This annotation requires the field names as how they are in the output; thus SNAKE CASE like `"alpha2_code"` and **not** `"alpha2Code"` as the Java property name.

Now we have a requirement to create YAML as out put as well (based on the same model).
But the naming convention for the YAML output needs to be KEBAB CASE.

Is there a smart way to solve this?

What I'm thinking of is to move the `@JsonPropertyOrder` to mix-ins and to introduce `CountrySnakeMixin` and `CountryKebabMixin` mix-in classes and use these in separate object mappers.

For this simple example it seems quite straightforward but with a model of 50 - 100 classes this becomes a maintenance nightmare.

Answer (score 0):

I tested

> This annotation requires the field names as how they are in the
> output

as not correct:

```
@JsonPropertyOrder({
    "id",
    "alpha2Code",
    "alpha3Code",
    "name"
})
```

works as intended, also changing the order, both in snake and kebab case.